# Are there Dataflow Log Appenders?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is it possible to register logback appenders in Dataflow?

With Beam, I'm able to define an appender for the DirectRunner, but when I deploy to Dataflow, it no longer seems to work. Is this just my logback.xml getting lost or is it because the runner has its own separate root logger?

Answer (score 0):

The Dataflow runner is in charge of orchestrating and paralelizing your pipeline to run in a distributed environment. As part of that it manages logging by using SLF4J.

If you can get logback to work on top of one of the supported libraries, or simply use one of them directly, you should be able to get your job's log messages on cloud logging.

The doc is for the Dataflow SDK, but it should apply equally for beam: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/logging

Comment: I was looking into hooking into the logging system to report errors to an external service, because cloud logging is terrible at error aggregation, and Stackdriver Error Reporting isn't supported (yet?)

Emitting the actual messages isn't my problem.